# Updating a document in Liferay without invoking workflow, but the file version need to change

Tags: tags, liferay-6, document, categories

I'm trying to update a document into the Liferay(version 6.2) Documents and Media programmatically taking excel as input which contains categories and tags of the document.
However, the document I was updating lies in a folder that has workflow.

I'm using the the following Liferay API to update the document,

```
DLAppServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(fileEntryId, sourceFileName, mimeType, title, description, changeLog, majorVersion, is, size, serviceContext)
```

This is working fine but it is invoking the workflow, which I don't have to.
So I used this API,

```
AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(userId, groupId, DLFileEntry.class.getName(), dlFileEntryId, categoryIds, tagNames);
```

This is updating the document with the given categories and tags and not invoking the workflow, but the file version is not getting changed, which is mandatory for me as I have to publish these documents from **Stage** to **Live**

So, I'm in need of an API or a workaround that does not trigger a workflow but changes the version of the file while updating it.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Harsha, have you tried DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry() method.

Comment: Yeah, I did but it also invokes the workflow